# android facebook sliding menus

Tags: android, slidingmenu

In my application I want to create two sliding menus: from left to right and from right to left; like for facebook one is for menu and the other is for chat.
How can i get both the sliding menus using jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu API by github?

Comment: I have answered this in another question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15242825/sliding-menu-using-jfeinstein10-library/19688948#19688948

Answer (score 5):

tried my own implementation [FacebookSlideOutMenu](https://github.com/srikanthgr/FacebookSlideOutmenu)

Answer (score 1):

Try the great [6wunderkinder Sliding Layer Library](https://github.com/6wunderkinder/android-sliding-layer-lib). It is *very simple to use* and you can add two sliding layers to the same activity, one from right and one from left.

Other libraries worth looking at:

- [SlidingMenu](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu)
- [android-menudrawer](http://simonvt.github.io/android-menudrawer/)
- [LibSlideMenu](https://github.com/bk138/LibSlideMenu)