# Secondary menu using jfeinstein10/ SlidingMenu library

Tags: android, slidingdrawer, android-sliding, slidingmenu

[image]I have a requirement to implement the sliding drawer in android. I'm using the  jfeinstein10/ SlidingMenu library to get my sliding drawing component which will basically open a listview. However, onclick of the list menu item ,a secondary menu with another list should slide down the main menu.

MainActivity class which instantiates the SlidingMenu

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sliding_menu_demo);
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);
        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        getData();
        ListItemAdapter listadapter = new ListItemAdapter(data, this);
        listView.setAdapter(listadapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int item,
                    long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(SlidingMenuDemo.this, "item clicked " + item,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();


            }
        });
        getSlidingMenu().setBehindOffset(250);
        getSlidingMenu().setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        getSlidingMenu().setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);

    }
```

Comment: Could you please reformulate your problem. What behavior do you want?

Comment: I would like to know how I can get the secondary menu (sub item list) on click of the main menu list.

Answer (score 1):

I implemented it by using nested menus. It is not the most elegant solution, but so far works pretty well.

More details here:
[How to implement two level slidingmenu in Android using jfeinstein10 / SlidingMenu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14619123/how-to-implement-two-level-slidingmenu-in-android-using-jfeinstein10-slidingme/17829011#17829011)

Comment: Thanks. I tweaked the android sliding drawer component. This proved to be a better solution.